# directing different buttons to the same page but displaying different things

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am writing an app for a Windows 8 phone. I'd like to direct a number of different buttons to the same page, the part that I'm struggling with is getting the page to display different things when the buttons are pressed. Is this possible? If it's possible, how to do it?

Comment: there is a thing called passing parameters between pages.

Comment: There is a lot of ways this can be achieved. If you want to pass more complex messages, this approach isn't gonna wok for you. The think you can use then is passing objects between pages. Of course you can also build your application according to MVVM pattern(recommended) or use singletons(not recommended, but can be used). There are plentiful tutorials on the net for all three. Just look up "passing objects between pages windows phone 8", "model-view-viewmodel windows phone 8" or "singleton pattern"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send different QueryString parameters when you navigate to another page, example:
From Page1 to TargePage

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=" + 
                                      "From Page1", UriKind.Relative));
```

From Page2 to TargetPage

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=" + 
                                      "From Page2", UriKind.Relative));
```

In the TargetPage

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            string msg = "";

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))

                textBlock1.Text = msg;           
        }
```

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

That's one way, or you can have some public object in the `App` class which is accessible across the application.

Comment: or you can pass objects and variables between pages.... using override of OnNavigatedFrom method....

Comment: or you can use MVVM pattern...or combine those together

Comment: thanks, basically Im want a different message to show at the top of the page each time one of the buttons have been pressed, how do I sort that out on the page that I'm wanting the info to be displayed on?

Answer (score 0):

As AD.Net Wrote, The thing you need to do is pass parameters between pages.

(DIDN'T have time to test the code, just wrote it up my head so it might contain mistakes, if someone sees them please edit them out)

### Let's demonstrate this on an example:

I have three buttons on my page, and every time I click one of them, I will be navigated to second page, but each button will render the page with different backround:

1. Lets create an App and make two pages, say... **Page1.xaml** and **Page2.xaml**
2. Now on **Page1** using designer add three buttons and give this buttons their event handlers for **Click** event

   ```
   <Button x:Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click" />
   <Button x:Name="btn2" Click="btn2_Click" />
   <Button x:Name="btn3" Click="btn3_Click" />
   ```

   (If you actually wrote the code by hand, the event handlers should create themselves automatically and stubs should be prepared for them in code-behind)

   And In each of these methods let's set up a simple command so it looks like:

   ```
   private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml?parameter=Red",UriKind.Relative));
     //You can add different parameter. I'll add Red,Blue and Green
   }
   ```
3. Almost there...On Page2.xaml, I'll go to codebehind (the Page2.xaml.cs file) and add this funny little thing:

   ```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
       if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("parameter"))
       {
             string val = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];
             switch(val)
             {
                 case "Red":
                      this.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red);
                      break;
                 case "Blue":
                      this.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
                      break;
                 case "Green":
                      this.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green);
                      break;
                 default:
                      this.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black);
                      break;
             }
       }
   }
   ```

### AND ITS THERE!